# cannot bind data from sqlliteData-base to simplecursoradaptor

Tags: java, android

I don´t know how to connect the data  my array   String [] station = {"København", "Grenaa", "Hanstholm"}; in my MyListActivity to the simpleCursorAdaptor 
I have made a SQLitedatabase, a Helperclass and anActivityclass - but I get the error " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'København' does not exist". I have additional code - but this code should be sufficient I think.
Any help would really be appreciated.

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
String [] station = {"København", "Grenaa", "Hanstholm"};
Cursor stations;
SQLiteDatabase db;
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DBAdapter  dbaAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
    dbaAdapter.open();
    Cursor stations = dbaAdapter.getStations();

    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stations,station,new int [] {
            android.R.id.text1
    });
    setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String value = station[(int)id];
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(TravelActivity.SELECTED_STATION_NAME, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("station")));
    this.setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);

    cursor.close();
    finish();


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    db.close();

}
```

}

```
public class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String DB_NAME = "database";
    String DESTINATION = "DESTINATION";
    int version = 1;



    public MyHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, "travel.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String TRAVELS = ( "create table travels (_id integer primary key autoincrement, start text, slut text)");
        String STATIONS = ( "create table stations (_id integer primary key autoincrement, start text)" );
        db.execSQL(TRAVELS);
        db.execSQL(STATIONS);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ");
        onCreate(db);

    }
}



public class DBAdapter {
    MyHelper myHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    String TABLE_STATIONS = "stations";
    String TABLE_TRAVELS = "travels";
    String START = "start";
    String SLUT = "slut";
    String ID_COL = "_id";
    Context context;

    public static final int NUMBER_TRAVELS = 1;


    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
        myHelper = new MyHelper(context);

    }

    public void open() {
        db = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    public void close() {
        myHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor getTravels() {
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TRAVELS,new String[]{ID_COL,START,SLUT},null,null,null,null,START);
      return cursor;
    }


    public void saveTravels(String start, String slut) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(START,start);
        values.put(SLUT,slut);
        db.insert(TABLE_TRAVELS,null,values);



    }

    public Cursor getStations() {
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_STATIONS,new String[]{ID_COL,START},null,null,null,null,START);
        return cursor;

    }

    public void saveStations(String start) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(START,start);
        db.insert(TABLE_TRAVELS,null,values);
    }

}
```

Comment: where exactly are u getting the error? are you doing cursor.moveToNext/MoveToFirst before using the cursor values?

Comment: your database helper class is incomplete, google about it and learn more about sqlite.

Comment: I get the error whe I compile the progam.

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated by your SimpleCursorAdapter constructor :

> SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
>   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stations,station,new int [] {
>               android.R.id.text1
>       });

The 4td parameter is the column names, so a String array with START and/or SLUT values in your case.

Comment: Can you post your new constructor line code and the complete logcat error pls ?

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DBAdapter  dbaAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbaAdapter.open();
        Cursor stations = dbaAdapter.getStations();


        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stations,START ,new int [] {
                android.R.id.text1
        });
        setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    }

Comment: I can not compile with this new constructor, because there is no reference to START in MyListActivity-class, so I can show the original error - and your suggestion (as I understand it).
I must also explain, that I am infact able to compile with my original code - it is when I click the button with the lstener in MyListActivity, that It crash
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stations,START ,new int [] {
                android.R.id.text1

Comment: (I exceeded number of characters in my previous comment - so I had to split it in to)
logCat (on original code)
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.utzon.myapplicationlessonfive/com.example.utzon.myapplicationlessonfive.MyListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.example.utzon.myapplicationlessonfive.DBAdapter.START' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)

Comment: Make START public, static and final : public static final String START = "start";
And use this constructor line : SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stations ,new String [] { DBAdapter.START} ,new int [] { android.R.id.text1});